# How to append JSON objects to a list?

Tags: python, json, list, append

I'm trying to append JSON objects to form a list of JSON objects.

```
def GenIndentifier(options):
    data=json.dumps([identifier,hex_dig])
    return data
```

The data here is a valid JSON object as follows:

`["27780741708467800000001", "e5073922dbb7a278769d52277d49c6ad3017b1ba"]`

Afterwards, I loop through the GenIdentifier function to generate many JSON objects:

```
data=[]
for i in range(0,2,1):
    ...
    data.append(GenIndentifier(options))
print data
```

Now the list of JSON data is not a valid JSON format because of some single quotations marks that pop up:

```
['["27780741708467800000000", 
"f798d2cd9aec1b98fb48b34fd249fe19c06a4a1d"]',
'["27780741708467800000001",       
"e5073922dbb7a278769d52277d49c6ad3017b1ba"]']
```

Any idea how to solve that?
I've searched and googled but in vain.

Comment: this does not seem to be JSON data. what you're working with, are simple lists. JSON usually follows a key-value format.

Comment: @PrateekDewan nonsense. The original value is perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp i'd let you decide

Comment: ...which says that arrays are valid JSON.

Comment: well.. fair enough.

Comment: @PrateekDewan - W3Schools.com is not definitiive and, in my experience, is usually misleading. JSON syntax is defined here: http://www.json.org/ and here http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Comment: makes sense. i'd update my pointers!

Comment: @Joseph, is your goal to have a single valid JSON string representing a list of pairs? Or is your goal to have a list of valid JSON strings, each representing a single pair?

Comment: @Robᵩ ..I'm trying to have a single valid JSON representing a list of pairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that you are dumping your data to JSON inside GenIndentifier, then appending that JSON string to a list.

Instead you should move the JSON conversion out of that function, and do it at the end:

```
def GenIndentifier(options):
    data = [identifier, hex_dig]
    return data

data = []
for i in range(0, 2, 1):
    ...
    data.append(GenIndentifier(options))
data = json.dumps(data)
print data
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: There is the output
'[["27780741708467800000000", "f798d2cd9aec1b98fb48b34fd249fe19c06a4a1d"], ["27780741708467800000001", "e5073922dbb7a278769d52277d49c6ad3017b1ba"]]'
a valid JSON but with two extra single quotes

Comment: That looks valid to me. The single quotes are just showing that the whole thing is a string, surely?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `json.dumps()` it converts the object, in this case a list of 2 elements, to a JSON formatted string.  You are then taking that list of strings, and appending them to a list.

If what you are looking for is a single JSON formatted list of lists, you would want to avoid doing the `json.dumps()` inside the `GenIdentifier` object, and simply return a list from that function. Then at the end, where you do the `print data`, instead do `print json.dumps(data)`

```
def GenIndentifier(options):
    data=[identifier,hex_dig]
    return data

data=[]
for i in range(0,2,1):
    ...
    data.append(GenIndentifier(options))
data = json.dumps(data)
print data
```

This will result in the following:

```
[["27780741708467800000000", "f798d2cd9aec1b98fb48b34fd249fe19c06a4a1d"],
 ["27780741708467800000001", "e5073922dbb7a278769d52277d49c6ad3017b1ba"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: There is the output '[["27780741708467800000000", "f798d2cd9aec1b98fb48b34fd249fe19c06a4a1d"], ["27780741708467800000001", "e5073922dbb7a278769d52277d49c6ad3017b1ba"]]' 
a valid JSON but with two extra single quotes

Comment: The single quotes come from the fact that `json.dumps` returns a string, and when you print a string object, it is wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: To fix, simply change the print line.

Comment: `print "%s" % data` should print without the single quotes.

Answer (score -2):

Does this work??

```
data=[]
for i in range(0,2,1):
    ...
    data.append(GenIndentifier(options)[i])
print data
```

- notice I added the [i] so that you will index into the data before you append it.

Comment: Right now, you're indexing into the return value of `append`, which is `None`.

Comment: There @jojonas that should fix it, I moved the [i] into the brackets as it should have been